# Next-easiest graphics rendering faster than GDI+?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, graphics, gdi+

I have a GDI+ program that I've thoroughly optimized (batching calls with `GraphicsPath`, `DrawLines`, etc.), but it's still slow at rendering (takes a few seconds to draw a complex map with anti-aliasing).

There is no way to make my GDI+ faster, so I'm looking for an alternative.

What is my next-easiest/lightweight alternative (with at least 20x faster performance or so) for drawing lines/circles/rectangles on the screen with antialiasing, if:

1. I need compatibility with Windows XP?
2. I don't need compatibility with Windows XP?

I'm looking into DirectDraw and Direct2D right now, but I haven't even figured out how to draw basic shapes on the screen with them. I might consider OpenGL too, but I'm not sure where to start since I've never used it.

Comment: DirectDraw is deprecated so I would advise against it (it isn't even in DirectX 8+ anymore). Direct2D and DirectWrite aren't available on XP. Direct2D or DirectDraw seem the way to go if you don't care about XP (e.g. Chrome, Firefox use Direct2D, Office 2013 uses DirectDraw). Direct3D or OpenGL if you need XP support.

Comment: Downvote is not mine, but this looks *a lot* like a recommendation question, and these are off-topic, as you know. Maybe the question can be refocused on the current algorithms you use and how well they may fare under a different environment?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: This isn't an algorithm question, my algorithms are much faster than the GDI+ rendering. The bottleneck really *is* GDI+. Not sure what makes it a "recommendation" question... I'm asking what APIs are available, I'm not what software I should buy or something like that.

Comment: @dtech: Wait, DirectDraw isn't available on XP? Are you sure?

Comment: @Mehrdad [DirectDraw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw) is, but [DirectWrite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectWrite) isn't. DirectDraw is obsolete though and DirectX 7-. (I mentioned DirectDraw the last two times when I meant DirectWrite)

Comment: @dtech: Oops I forgot about the difference as well, thanks.

Comment: @dtech: Is it even possible to draw basic antialiased shapes with DirectDraw or Direct2D? Looking at the documentation I feel like the only thing they do is give you back a buffer and leave you to figure out how to deal with the drawing pixel-by-pixel yourself...

Comment: Direct2D is almost like a swap-in for GDI+, just faster and cleaner. The drawing functions are exposed via the [`ID2D1RenderTarget` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @RogerRowland: I tried it and it worked! It's so much faster now, thanks. Would you like to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct2D is almost like a swap-in for GDI+, just faster and cleaner. The drawing functions are exposed via the [`ID2D1RenderTarget` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371766%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Unlike Direct2D, GDI+ is not hardware accelerated, so you should notice a huge improvement in speed of rendering. Anti-aliased drawing and alpha-blending operations are part of the package now.

Comment: Direct2D is not always faster. It depends on the bottleneck. Sometimes it is more a memory bottleneck, than a rendering bottleneck.

Comment: @Frank Direct2D is never slower. If you are memory bandwidth limited with Direct2D, you are memory bandwidth limited, regardless of which way you do your rendering. Selecting an appropriate render target for Direct2D can seriously reduce memory traffic, though, an option you do not have when rendering with GDI or GDI+, for example.

Comment: Direct2D uses hardware acceleration by default, which can be slower than software rendering, depending on the hardware, the free memory in the system, and the way the video hardware uses system memory. GDI+ was designed in an era when hardware resources were more constrained; it is not the fastest system, but it can outperform Direct2D. Many people use software rendering with Visual Studio because it is faster on their system; this is WPF, but the underlying issue is the same.

Comment: I like Direct2D and recommend it over GDI+ for newer work. I just don't like blanket statements about performance, when there are so many factors to consider. GDI+ does have the advantage of always working on all systems, whereas Direct2D can be buggy.

Comment: I believe for professional software and clients with old machines GDI+ and Direct2D should be supported.